# SQS message acknowledgement

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

My Sring Boot application listens Amazon SQS queue. Right now I need to implement correct message acknowledgement  - I need to receive a message, do some business logic a only after that in case of success I need to ack the message(delete the message from the queue). For example, in case of error in my business logic the message must be re-enqueued.

This is my SQS config:

```
    /**
     * AWS Credentials Bean
     */
    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials awsCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
    }

    /**
     * AWS Client Bean
     */
    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS amazonSQSAsyncClient() {
        AmazonSQS sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCredentials());
        sqsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        return sqsClient;
    }

    /**
     * AWS Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean
    public SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        SQSConnectionFactory.Builder factoryBuilder = new SQSConnectionFactory.Builder(
                Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        factoryBuilder.setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {

            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return awsCredentials();
            }

            @Override
            public void refresh() {
            }

        });
        return factoryBuilder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Registering QueueListener for queueName
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new MyQueueListener()));
        messageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(queueName);

        return messageListenerContainer;
    }
```

My queue listener:

```
public class MyQueueListener {

    public void handleMessage(String messageContent) throws JMSException {
        //do some job
        //TODO: ack the message
    }
}
```

Right now I don't know how to ack the message from my listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` acknowledges the message before or after execution of `handleMessage` automatically. So you don't need to do anything.

But recommended with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` is to use transactions instead of client ack mode. Not sure if Amazon SQS has such option.

Comment: So what is the correct way of using acknowledgement in SQS in my case(it is not clear from your answer) ?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about explicit ack. Spring does it normally for you.

Comment: Do you guys know how to send explicit FAIL message?